# Stock footage creative commons license

Tags: editing

I'm making a travel documentary, and I'm missing a couple of shots of places which are quite touristy. E.g. Bikaner in India where there is a large red fort, the Nagour fort and Jodphur in the streets. Also the Delwari temple at Mount Abu.
I visited these places but they don't play a major part to my film, however, I would like to have a couple of shots of them if I can. Does anyone know of places to get stock open source footage, or contact people in those places who may be able to film for me - e.g. Couchsurfers?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try [CC-Search](http://search.creativecommons.org/), however use this wisely as some sites that are linked, do not always upload non-copyright footage, though you should be good for the most part.